# during login to a system is it better to compare the registered encrypted password with the inserted password after encrypting it or the opposite?

Tags: encryption, passwords

During login to a system, is it better to compare the registered encrypted password with the inserted password after encrypting it

or

compare the inserted password with the registered password after decrypting it?

And why?

Comment: I hope you mean "hashed" and not "encrypted"

Comment: Why are you "decrypting" passwords?

Comment: I mean using symmetric encryption

Comment: Then you need to explain a lot more about this system because it is not typical. We can't offer advice without understanding context.

Comment: why are you using encryption on passwords?

Comment: password can be encrypted not just file. and I'm new to this technique so if there is no need for using decryption to verify the password during login and it's enough to encrypt it then to compare it with the registered encrypted password at the database then let me know please.

Comment: @user221232 It's a bad technique, do not encrypt passwords. Hash them with a secure password hashing algorithm instead. You need to compare password hashes, not decrypt passwords and compare them.

Comment: Please look up "password hashing" on this site or Google - there are many well-established libraries and tools that will do it all properly for you.

Comment: Thank you @schroeder do you recommend hashing then encryption?

Comment: You do not encrypt passwords as part of logging in. That's not a personal recommendation: that's the only acceptable way to do it. If you encrypt passwords and decrypt them on your server, then you know what every user's password is!

Comment: Thank you @user do you recommend hashing then encryption?

Comment: If you hash properly, you do not need to also encrypt over top. The connection to the system should be encrypted (like with TLS).

Comment: @user221232 Everyone recommends hashing. It's an [industry standard.](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html)

Answer (score 4):

## Neither is good.

Encrypting passwords means storing them in a reversible format. An attacker, which gains access to your server, can steal the database and the decryption keys, which is only *marginally better* than storing them in plaintext.

## What to do instead

Use a Key-Derivation Function (KDF) designed to hash passwords, such as [Argon2](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2), [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt), [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) or [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). Benchmark your system and pick work-parameters that make it difficult for an attacker to crack your hashes.

## But why not encrypt them?

As mentioned above, encrypting them means that they can be decrypted by whoever has the key. If they are hashed, then the only way to gain access to them is to either observe them being inputted correctly, or to crack the hashes.

But you don't need to take my word for it. [OWASP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html), one of the most reputable organizations in the field of web application security, will tell you just the same.